# Error when sending a request to the Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I am fairly new to the backend. Anyway, I want to create an API that I can use in the front-end, the error I am facing when I try to send a request to the `localhost:5000/elements` Postman is giving me  `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000` if someone could help me it would be awesome. Thanks

```
var fs=require('fs');
var data=fs.readFileSync('books.json');
var elements=JSON.parse(data);
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors=require('cors');

const Port = 5000

app.listen(process.env.Port, () => console.log("Server Start at " + Port));

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(cors());
app.get('/elements',alldata);
function alldata(request,response)
{
    response.send(elements);
}
app.get('/elements/:element/',searchElement);
function searchElement(request,response)
{
    var word=request.params.element;
    word=word.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    console.log(word);
    console.log(elements[word]);
    if(elements[word])
    {
        var reply=elements[word];
        
    }
    else
    {
        var reply={
            status:"Not Found"
        }
    }
    console.log(reply.boil);
    response.send(reply);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem usually happens if you forget to run `npm start`.

Either way, I recommend moving the `app.listen` to the bottom of the code. It helps with readability, and it will mount all of code before running the Express server.

Your `process.env.Port` is also undefined. Change it to `const port = process.env.Port || 5000` so you can get a fallback value. Change it also in the `app.listen`.

Then, define `allData` and `searchElement` so they are located before the `app.get('/elements')`. Finally, after you have done all of this, make sure that the request type in Postman is `GET`.

Comment: @NicoIas D  I appreciate the help. Have a simple question,  could I deploy  this on Heroku, so I could get Fetch data in the front but this endpoint point would always be ```https://git.heroku.com/json-apibooooks.git/elements``` elements am I right

Comment: What's the front end that you're using? React? My answer will differ depending on your answer.

Comment: I see. Why don't you open a question, so I can answer it there?

Comment: I can open a question every 90 minutes

Comment: I see. Well, that's okay, I'll just answer it here. You can actually just make an `.env` file where you store the link to your API. When you make a request, just pass that url value. Further reading: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: yes but with that, I would be the only one who can  use it

Comment: Not necessarily. Environment variables are used globally throughout your application.

Comment: the link woulde be localhost:5000/elements, is it?

Comment: Yes, then, you just need to use `process.env.<your_variable>` in every API calls.

Answer (score 1):

`process.env.Port` is unrelated to `Port`.

It's

```
app.listen(Port, () => console.log("Server Start at " + Port));
```

Comment: I appreciate the help